# problems ... BeautifulSoup Parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<h2 class="sectionTitle">BACKGROUND</h2>
Mr. Paul J. Fribourg has bla bla</span>
<div style="margin-top:8px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_more(this);">Read Full Background</a>
</div>
```

I would like to extract information from Mr. Paul to blabla
Some webpage has `<p>` infront of Mr. Paul, so I could use `FindNext('p')`
However, some webpages do not have `<p>` like the example above..

this is my code for when there is `<p>`

```
background = bs2.find(text=re.compile("BACKGROUND"))
bb= background.findNext('p').contents
```

But when I don't have `<p>` how I could extract information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the example you have given us, but it looks to me that you could just get the next node after an `h2`. In this example, *Lewis Carroll* has a `p`-aragraph tag and your friend Paul has only a closing `span` tag:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html = '''
... <h2 class="sectionTitle">BACKGROUND</h2>
... <p>Mr. Lewis Carroll has bla bla</p>
... <div style="margin-top:8px;">
...     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_more(this);">Read Full Background</a>
... </div>
... <h2 class="sectionTitle">BACKGROUND</h2>
... Mr. Paul J. Fribourg has bla bla</span>
... <div style="margin-top:8px;">
...     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_more(this);">Read Full Background</a>
... </div>
... '''
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> headings = soup.findAll('h2', text='BACKGROUND')
>>> for section in headings:
...     p = section.findNext('p')
...     if p:
...         print '> ',  p.string
...     else:
...         print '> ', section.parent.next.next.strip()
...
>  Mr. Lewis Carroll has bla bla
>  Mr. Paul J. Fribourg has bla bla
```

---

Following comments:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> html = urlopen('http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/person.asp?personId=668561&privcapId=160900&previousCapId=285930&previousTitle=LOEWS%20CORP')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> headings = soup.findAll('h2', text='BACKGROUND')
>>> for section in headings:
...     paragraph = section.findNext('p')
...     if paragraph and paragraph.string:
...         print '> ', paragraph.string
...     else:
...         print '> ', section.parent.next.next.strip()
... 
>  Mr. Paul J. Fribourg has been the President of Contigroup Companies Inc. (for [...]
```

You may, of course, wish to check copyright notices, *et cetera*...

Comment: Thank you for kind answer! Actually, there is no <span> before Mr. Paul.. so if I run your code, Read Full Background is shown.... Would you mind letting me know the way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Willy: My original answer was based one what was apparently an edit to your question, where somebody had added a '<span>' tag. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: oh thank you sooo much! it is working really well.. but in my original website it doesn't work..:(( I would like to cry..

Comment: @Willy: Can you fix the HTML in the original website so that it's valid?

Comment: actually, the original website is this.. I am trying various ways to extract the information.. but I don't know why I always fail.. http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/person.asp?personId=668561&privcapId=160900&previousCapId=285930&previousTitle=LOEWS%20CORP

Comment: @Willy: Looks like you need a little tweak. See above.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Some webpage has`<p>`infront of Mr. Paul, so I could use FindNext('p') However, some webpages do not have`<p>`like the example above."*

You're not giving enough information to be able to recognize your string:

- fixed node structure e.g. getChildren()[1].getChildren()[0].text
- if it's preceded by the magic string 'BACKGROUND' as per your code, then your approach of finding the next node seems good - just don't build in an assumption that the tag name is 'p'
- regex (e.g. *"(Mr.|Ms.) ..."*)

Show us a HTML example when it does not have `<p>` in front of name?

Comment: Thank you for kind comments! I think your second point is correct.. string Background could be the magic string.. but I have been considering way to extract a text after the word.. I don't know.. it doesn't work..